# Three.js FogExp2 with max distance?

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

I understand FogExp2 takes in two parameters (color, density). Is there a way I can restrict the maximum distance FogExp2 applies to?

Here is my problem -- I draw the Sun (THREE.SphereGeometry) at the horizon but my fog color overrides the color of the Sun too! Is there a way to exempt the Sun from FogExp2?

Note: I do not prefer using THREE.Fog but rather a more real-looking, THREE.FogExp2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a mesh from being affected by scene fog, do this:

```
mesh.material.fog = false;
```

three.js r.69